# Can you use a key containing a dot (".") in i18next interpolation?

Tags: localization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

Is it possible to interpolate with a key containing a "." in i18n?

i.e. get this to work:

```
{
    "key": "Hi {{first.name}}"
}

i18next.t('key', { "first.name": 'Jane'});
// -> "Hi Jane"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, dot in a property name for interpolation is used as json dot notation.
So if you want to keep `"Hi {{first.name}}"` in your translations, you need to pass in the t options like this: `i18next.t('keyk', { first: { name: 'Jane' } })`